# Summation of logarithm $n\log(n)$

Tags: summation, logarithms, asymptotics

I'm solving a big O problem that resulted a part of the algorithm running in

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n/2} i \log i$$

I tried reducing it, using logarithmic identities into

$$\log\left(\prod_{i=0}^{n/2} i^i\right)$$

I was wondering if a) this was correct and b) if it can be simplified any further.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt okay thanks! Only thought of searching using "n", not "x".

Comment: :P Just so happens that I remembered that question :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint:
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{n/2} i \log i \; \sim \; \int_1^{n/2} x \log x \; \textbf{d}x $$